# async and await in console app

Tags: c#, .net

Given this is the code below I'd  expect to see this output:

----- Enter main 
----- Exit main 
----- 185ms passed

But instead, it acts synchronously and Foo blocks MainAsync from returning. Can anyone clarify?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }


    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----- Enter main");
        await Foo();
        Console.WriteLine("----- Exit main");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task Foo()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

        Console.WriteLine("----- " + (DateTime.Now - time).Milliseconds + "ms passed");
    }
}
```

Comment: `await` does not start anything. It waits for work to end. There is no need for a new keyword to start something. We always were able to do that.

Comment: Your getting (as everyone seems to do) threading and asynchounous programming mixed up.

Comment: Note that [GetResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult(v=vs.110).aspx) is not intended for use by consumer code. It is meant to be leveraged by mechanisms internal to the .NET framework libraries.

Comment: On a site note, you should not use `DateTime.Now` to determine how long a methods takes to run.  It doesn't have particularly high precision, and can be subject to oddities when, say, the system time/timezone changes or during ambiguous time periods such as around daylightsavings switches.  You should use `Stopwatch` to measure the time elapsed from the time you call one method until the time you call another.

Comment: If you want to use async / await in a console, take a look at this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html . There is some special setup that should be done to have it work properly.

Comment: @BradleyUffner is correct here - you can't count on async/await in a console application to behave in the same way as it does in a UI application without proper setup. Poorly advertised but true.

Comment: I am also on a async/await learning stage of C#, so I'd appreciate a simple answer for the following question. If we use async programming in console app, and therefore not blocking the thread, for which purposes can we use it while waiting for the result from the async method? If in UI app async helps with responsiveness, then I don't see any use scenarios within console app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`await Foo();` means that the rest of the method won't run until after the `Task` returned by `Foo` has completed.  That's what it means to `await` something; the method won't continue until that `Task` has completed.  As such, `Console.WriteLine("----- Exit main");` won't run until after `Foo` has completed, which won't be until after it has already written out the time it took.

Comment: What Servy said. On a side note, when you use await, unless you are dealing with a UI, you should always add .ConfigureAwait(false) Why? If you do not specify the default behavior is with a true parameter. It means that when the task is done, the continuation will be serialized back to the original thread that was awaiting. In the UI, this is often necessary because only the main thread can update the UI. But in server/background applications, this is wasted overhead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: I see... It looks like console apps are don't make a very good example when studying async/await business. Assuming I call Foo on a UI event handler, my understanding is that calling Foo will still block the event handler however the work will NOT be done on the UI thread. Execution of Foo - awaited code - is given to another thread. If I skip await in the event handler, Foo still executes asyncly but this time button1_Click will return before Foo finishes execution. Is that right?

Comment: @berk_canc No.  The click handler will complete as soon as the first `await` is hit, and whatever is in the method after that `await` will be schedule to run as soon as the operation being awaited finishes.  Assuming it's in the UI context (which it would be) that continuation would be scheduled to run in the UI thread, not just some thread pool thread (unless you explicitly told it *not* to, by, say, using `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  If you don't `await` the `Task` then whatever is in `Foo` will run after *starting* `Foo`, but before all of it has finished.

Comment: @berk_canc By the way, Keith is just wrong in his comment.  There is no synchronization context in your console app (until you do something to create one, which you have not done in your app) so adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` will do literally nothing, as there is nothing to capture even without it.

Comment: @Servy, thank you. Can you pls clarify this: "If you don't await the Task then whatever is in Foo will run after starting Foo, but before all of it has finished." What is all of it you are referring to?

Comment: @berk_canc Everything in `Foo`.